# Coordinate vector equation

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

I have the following bases which are bases of $\mathbb{R}^3$
$$B = ((1,1,1), (0,1,1), (0,0,1))$$
$$C = ((1,2,3), (-1,0,1), (1,0,1))$$
I need to find if this equation is correct
$$[(1,2,3)]_B = (1,1,1)^t ?$$

I do know how to calculate $[(1,2,3)]_B$ but i'm not sure how to calculate $(1,1,1)^t$

from my calculation I got
$[(1,2,3)]_B = (1, -1, 0)$

but how do I find $(1,1,1)^t$ ?

Comment: What does it mean to calculate $(1,1,1)^t$? There is nothing to calculate, it's a vector.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The $t$ means transpose here. So $(1,1,1)^t$ is exactly
$$\begin{pmatrix}1\\1\\1\end{pmatrix}$$

And if you calculate correctly, you should get that.

Comment: yeah I found my mistake in the matrix it is $[(1,2,3)]B=(1,1,1)$. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Actually, there is nothing to be computed. I mean that it is obvious that $[(1,2,3)]_B = \left( \begin{array}{c}
1 \\
1 \\
1 \end{array} \right)$ since $(1,2,3)$ is the sum of the three vectors of the base $B$.

The notation $(1,1,1)^t$ means as was already notice the transpose of the column.